# Data in lambda event is not persistent

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I want to pass some data from one lambda function to the other for which I am using lambda 'events'.

First lambda Function -

```
event['data'] = "value"
return event
```

Second Lambda Function -

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    value_of_data = event['data']
```

This works correctly sometimes and sometimes it gives the following error -

```
Error

KeyError
Cause
{
 "errorMessage": "'data'",
 "errorType": "KeyError",
 "stackTrace": [
  [
  "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
  276,
  "lambda_handler",
  "event_return = get_status(event)"
  "value_of_data = event['data']"
  ]
  ]
  }
```

Comment: Could you confirm how you're pass data from one lambda to another?

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace Using 'event'.

Comment: As in, you have two different lambda functions, and the first lambda function is invoking the second asynchronously using the boto3 invoke? Or they're connected by step functions? Or an outside script/application is invoking the first one, getting the response, and then passing that response to a second one?

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace They are connected by step functions

Comment: Can you post your step function definition (at least the two steps that link them) also, please? And ideally the full handler of the first lambda function.

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace Can we have more details? Generally the input passed to the step functions is accessible to each lambda. If you want to reference the output of a specific lambda I recommand to use `"ResultPath": "$.your_lambda_output",` then reference to such output as `event['your_lambda_output']`